# Bitmap display with wxPython looks twisted

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython

First question here so please be kind

I have read through most of the related questions and have managed to resolve most of my issues. A lot of good information here.

- Python 3.7
- wxPython 4.0.4
- gtk2 (phoenix)
- wxWidgets 3.0.5

My skills: Programming since gwBasic but beginner with Python (3 months) and noobie with wxPython (1 week)

I am trying to display the images from a camera (1270x720) using `wx.StaticBitmap`. The GUI was created using `wxFormBuilder` and then modified to suit my needs. All this with thanks to many here. I already have most of this application worked out and functional using OpenCV but now the GUI is proving much more difficult than I am used to.

I finally have the image displaying but it looks like my old TV when the horizontal hold would go out. I use `cv2.imshow()` in the same function to show that the image is valid and it shows good.

[image: image display screenshot]

The portion of the code that initializes the widgets:

```
class fullFrame ( wx.Frame ):

def __init__(self, parent, id, iframe, **kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 1612,800 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    ## ** Updated SetSizeHintsSz to SetSizeHints
    self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

    fullSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

    imgSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    self.pnl = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.pnl.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )
    self.pnl.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 1280,720 ) )
    ########### ** ###########
    ## Added image controls ##
    ########### ** ###########
    self.Ready = False
    self.iframe = iframe
    self.imageSize = (1280, 720)
    self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    ## ** Updated wx.EmptyImage to wx.Image
    self.image = wx.Image(self.imageSize[0], self.imageSize[1])
    ## ** Updated wx.BitmapFromImage to wx.Bitmap
    self.imageBit = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
    self.staticBit = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pnl, wx.ID_ANY, self.imageBit)

    self.vbox.Add(self.staticBit)
    self.height, self.width = iframe.shape[:2]
    self.bmp = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(self.height, self.width, iframe)
    self.set_image()
    self.Ready = True

    ########### ** ###########
    ## End image controls ##
    ########### ** ###########

    imgSizer.Add( self.pnl, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


    fullSizer.Add( imgSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
```

The image update function.

```
    ## ** Added function to diplay image
def set_image(self):
    newframe = cv2.cvtColor(self.iframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(newframe)
    self.staticBit.SetBitmap(self.bmp)
    self.Refresh()
    cv2.imshow('Actual with OpenCV2', self.iframe)
```

Also, the bitmap appears to be filling just more than half of the panel, whereas the full image is shown by OpenCV. I thought maybe I had the height and width variables reversed but when I tried swapping them the issue simply went horizontal. Either way it only filled about 720 of the 1280 pixels.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, whats the use of `cv2.cvtColor` in `set_image` method?

Comment: @asaf the image frame used by <code>OpenCV2</code> is in BRG. The format required by <code>wxPython</code> is RBG. Or maybe vice versa. Either way I need to swap the color data order.

Comment: I still have no idea what caused this, but I am past it. I started over with the wxPython layout, making no changes to the image processing. I found that I was adding the panel to my sizer, instead of the oter way around. <br/>
    was 'imgSizer.Add( self.imgPnl, 0, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )'<br/>
    is now 'self.imgPnl.SetSizer(self.imgSizer)'<br/><br/>
 I was also adding the imgSizer to fullSizer, which is also not correct.<br/> So, with a brand new layout, the images are showing up properly. Not answered, just worked around